# How do i find the root of: "threadid=4 reacting to signal 3"?

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am currently developing a android game with AndEngine.
It really works great so far, except for one problem i cannot seem to figure out how to solve. 
Every time i upload the game to my phone (to debug) and let it start, the gameplay (movement) freezes or goes extremely slow for a couple of seconds and a "threadid=4 reacting to signal 3" message appears in the LogCat. 
If i then close the game and start it up again from the phone itself (not with eclipse) it seems to be completely fine. Reading about that message i pulled the log from the device but i am unable to find out how to tackle this problem. Any ideas? This is the part for my app:

```
JNI: CheckJNI is off; workarounds are off; pins=0; globals=160

DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)

"main" prio=5 tid=1 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41858578 self=0x417cc1b8
  | sysTid=21363 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1075159292
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=33 stm=23 core=0
  at java.lang.VMThread.sleep(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1013)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:995)
  at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTouch(Engine.java:434)
  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7386)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2211)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1954)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2211)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1954)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2211)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1954)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2228)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1471)
  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2424)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7571)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3883)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3778)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3540)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5419)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5399)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5370)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5493)
  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:182)
  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:174)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:5472)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5512)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:530)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"GLThread 6183" prio=5 tid=14 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41b077a8 self=0x40010610
  | sysTid=21380 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073810016
  | state=D schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=304 stm=48 core=0
  #00  pc 0001b420  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+12)
  #01  pc 0002c257  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
  #02  pc 0001b539  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+140)
  #03  pc 0001ba23  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::waitForResponse(android::Parcel*, int*)+42)
  #04  pc 0001bc2b  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::transact(int, unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+118)
  #05  pc 00018489  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::BpBinder::transact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+30)
  #06  pc 0002333f  /system/lib/libgui.so
  #07  pc 00026e81  /system/lib/libgui.so (android::Surface::dequeueBuffer(ANativeWindowBuffer**, int*)+92)
  #08  pc 000271d1  /system/lib/libgui.so (android::Surface::hook_dequeueBuffer_DEPRECATED(ANativeWindow*, ANativeWindowBuffer**)+32)
  #09  pc 00000734  /system/vendor/lib/libpvrANDROID_WSEGL.so
  at com.google.android.gles_jni.EGLImpl.eglSwapBuffers(Native Method)
  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.swap(GLSurfaceView.java:1142)
  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1528)
  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1242)

"UpdateThread" prio=5 tid=13 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41b02be8 self=0x40074b50
  | sysTid=21379 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073758872
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=102 stm=17 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x41b02dd0> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=13 (UpdateThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:159)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2019)
  at org.andengine.engine.Engine$EngineLock.waitUntilCanUpdate(Engine.java:965)
  at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:573)
  at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:858)

"SoundPool" prio=5 tid=12 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41b02f40 self=0x40004b38
  | sysTid=21377 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1283308752
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  #00  pc 0001c6ec  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
  #01  pc 0000e824  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
  #02  pc 0000e884  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+64)
  #03  pc 0006266f  /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::SoundPool::run()+20)
  #04  pc 0004f375  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+68)
  #05  pc 000115e5  /system/lib/libutils.so
  #06  pc 0000cb48  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
  #07  pc 0000ccc4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+208)
  #08  pc 00001b34  <unknown>
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"SoundPoolThread" prio=5 tid=11 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41b02de8 self=0x400044e0
  | sysTid=21378 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074219272
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  #00  pc 0001c6ec  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
  #01  pc 0000e824  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
  #02  pc 0000e884  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+64)
  #03  pc 00062ad9  /system/lib/libmedia.so
  #04  pc 00062b2b  /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::SoundPoolThread::read()+16)
  #05  pc 00062cd7  /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::SoundPoolThread::run()+14)
  #06  pc 0004f375  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+68)
  #07  pc 000115e5  /system/lib/libutils.so
  #08  pc 0000cb48  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
  #09  pc 0000ccc4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+208)
  #10  pc 000014dc  <unknown>
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder_2" prio=5 tid=10 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41ada858 self=0x4167d840
  | sysTid=21375 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1097324024
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  #00  pc 0001b41c  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
  #01  pc 0002c257  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
  #02  pc 0001b539  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+140)
  #03  pc 0001bcd7  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+154)
  #04  pc 0001fae9  /system/lib/libbinder.so
  #05  pc 00011af1  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
  #06  pc 0004f375  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+68)
  #07  pc 000115e5  /system/lib/libutils.so
  #08  pc 0000cb48  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
  #09  pc 0000ccc4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+208)
  #10  pc 0000283c  <unknown>
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder_1" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41ad9558 self=0x4167d0a0
  | sysTid=21374 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1097066864
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  #00  pc 0001b41c  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
  #01  pc 0002c257  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
  #02  pc 0001b539  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+140)
  #03  pc 0001bcd7  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+154)
  #04  pc 0001fae9  /system/lib/libbinder.so
  #05  pc 00011af1  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
  #06  pc 0004f375  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+68)
  #07  pc 000115e5  /system/lib/libutils.so
  #08  pc 0000cb48  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
  #09  pc 0000ccc4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+208)
  #10  pc 0000209c  <unknown>
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=8 WAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41ad6448 self=0x4163de10
  | sysTid=21373 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1097065056
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x418606e0> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.waitForObject(Daemons.java:230)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:207)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

"FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=7 WAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41ad6298 self=0x4163d4c8
  | sysTid=21372 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1097062680
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x41849568> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:102)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:73)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

"ReferenceQueueDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 WAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41ad6130 self=0x4163bfe8
  | sysTid=21371 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1097060336
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x41849490> 
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
  at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:130)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=5 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41ad57f8 self=0x4163b8e8
  | sysTid=21370 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1097053856
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=21 stm=8 core=0
  #00  pc 0001c6ec  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
  #01  pc 0000e824  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
  #02  pc 0000e884  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+64)
  #03  pc 00073227  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #04  pc 00054491  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #05  pc 0000cb48  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
  #06  pc 0000ccc4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+208)
  #07  pc 000068e4  <unknown>
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"JDWP" daemon prio=5 tid=4 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41ad5710 self=0x4163c940
  | sysTid=21369 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1097058040
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  #00  pc 0001b56c  /system/lib/libc.so (select+20)
  #01  pc 00060edf  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #02  pc 00063a19  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #03  pc 00054491  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #04  pc 0000cb48  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
  #05  pc 0000ccc4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+208)
  #06  pc 0000793c  <unknown>
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=3 RUNNABLE
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41ad5618 self=0x4dbaf3a0
  | sysTid=21368 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1304097112
  | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2 stm=2 core=0
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"GC" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41ad5538 self=0x4dbae9a0
  | sysTid=21367 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1304100128
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  #00  pc 0001c6ec  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
  #01  pc 0000e824  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
  #02  pc 0000e884  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+64)
  #03  pc 00071eb7  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #04  pc 00054491  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #05  pc 0000cb48  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
  #06  pc 0000ccc4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+208)
  #07  pc 0000b99c  <unknown>
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

NATIVE THREADS:
"AudioTrack" sysTid=21486 nice=-16 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
```

Since there is no line having something directly to do with my app i am unable to find out where the error occurs.
Is there something wrong with AndEngine, or has this something to do with uploading the app via eclipse?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is the problem, but you can try "bluestacks" app player, if there is no problem, maybe there is something with your phone.

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for your answer. I am already debugging with BlueStacks and my Phone. Same problem on both...with a different log.